# add labels to scrollviewer programmatically WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I am reading data from a Xml file and I want to add these data to a scroll viewer. How can I add labels to scroll viewer programmatically ?

Comment: You use ListBox and set ItemsSource to the xml data.